# std::array Can't compare between two arrays with my class as its element

Tags: c++, stdarray

I have two std::array same size and store the same element type (a class that I wrote) when I compare them using `==` operator compiler throws this error: `...\include\xutility(2919): error C2672: 'operator __surrogate_func': no matching overloaded function found`.

I tried comparing tow arrays with vectors as their elements and it worked but comparing arrays with any class I write I'm getting that error.

Test class:

```
class Class {

    int i;

public:
    Class() {}
    Class(const Class& other) {}
    Class(Class&& other) {}
    ~Class() {}

    Class operator= (const Class& other) {}
    Class operator= (Class&& other) {}

    BOOL operator== (const Class& other) {}

};
```

Comparison:

```
   std::array<Class, 3> a0 = {};
   std::array<Class, 3> a1 = {};

      if (a0 == a1)
        "COOL";
```

Error I'm getting:

```
...\include\xutility(2919): error C2672: 'operator __surrogate_func': no matching overloaded function found
```

Comment: Why are you returning `BOOL` instead of `bool` and why is there no return statement in your functions?

Comment: Because you're not comparing `a0` and `a1`, but the arrays.

Comment: @Eli Sadoff a1 and a0 are arrays lol

Comment: @LorenceHernandez I know. The operator was overloaded for `Class` not for `std::array<Class, 3>`

Comment: I realize that I missed a word. I meant the contents of `a0` and `a1`.

Comment: @krzaq BOOL and bool are the same, I am using windows.h and for some reason, I got used using BOOL.

Comment: @user3196144 then `BOOL` definitely isn't the same as `bool`. It's a typedef for `int`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at `std::array`'s definition of [`operator==`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/operator_cmp), you'll notice that it's defined for const arrays. That means you can only access elements as const, which your `Class`'s `operator==` doesn't do.

Change it to take implicit this as const:

```
BOOL operator== (const Class& other) const { /*...*/ }
                                     ^^^^^
```

While at it, you probably want to return `bool` instead of `BOOL`:

```
bool operator== (const Class& other) const { /*...*/ }
```

Comment: The link points to one answer of yours that has nothing to do with the question, not the actual definition of `operator==`. Is this intended?

Comment: @Rakete1111 no, it must be a copy-paste error. Edited. Thanks!